# Programmatically detect Terraform input and/or output variables

Tags: terraform

I would like to automate some Terraform documentation and CI/CD checks related to input variables. Is there any way to do one or more of the following:

1. detect what **input variables** a specific module will take
2. detect what **output variables** a specific module can generate
3. detect the **data type** and **description** fields of the above (when applicable)

If not possible, I guess I will have to resort to regex parsing of all files in a module folder - but this seems like brute force, and far from ideal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a good bit of success with the [terraform-docs](https://github.com/segmentio/terraform-docs) open-source tool. You essentially point it to your module and it generates fairly standard looking docs in the format you provide.

This tool can also output JSON if you'd like a raw tree of data to process yourself.

If you're looking for something a little more "low level" you could also look into the module that powers `terraform-docs`: [terraform-config-inspect](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-config-inspect).

Comment: I stumbled on this myself after posting this question. Yes, it's been working like a charm. Thanks so much!